# Why is this LockService not working as expected when sending email?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, lock-service

I'm using `LockService` when sending emails, but when multiple users run it at the same time, it throws the error: `Service invoked too many times...`

Here's some log, showing the failures:

[image]

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(3000); // wait 03 seconds for others' use of the code section and lock to stop and then proceed
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Someone has just sent an Email. Try it again 3 seconds later.');
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b> Server Busy please try after some time <p>")
    // In case this a server side code called asynchronously you return a error code and display the appropriate message on the client side
    //return "Error: Server busy try again later... Sorry :("
  }
  
   /*
   Gets certain data from current row. These are used as criteria
   */

    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Text", name + " BODY.", { name: 'Diplay Custom Name as Sender' });
    
//Looks for a matching record in another sheet to mark its adjacent column as sent ("Yes")
    for (var n = 0; n < formRespValues.length; n++) {
      if (formRespValues[n][1] == testNo) {
        formRespSheet.getRange('M' + (2 + n)).setValue('Yes');
      }
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // applies all pending spreadsheet changes
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Comment: In your situation, when `3000` of `lock.waitLock(3000)` is increased like for example `30000`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Can't believe, @Tanaike! Such a stupid mistake by me. I'm about to give it up! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. If that could resolve your issue, can you post it as an answer? By this, I thought that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157973/#comment125784324_71157973), a short time within [`waitLock(timeoutInMillis)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#waitlocktimeoutinmillis) or [`tryLock(timeoutInMillis)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#trylocktimeoutinmillis) may prevent the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) from working as expected.

To ensure the correct functioning, try setting a time that is largely greater than the execution time of your script. If it is less than this, the lock will "open" prematurely, and cause errors such as those outlined in the question.

###### Documentation :

- [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)
- [Class Lock](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock)